# Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to test my database with Mocking using Nunit test. I wanted to see if the method I am using is being called. I am trying to find out if the method Insert() is being called from the method InsertTours().

When I run the unit test the program gives me an error message saying: 
`Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times: _ => _.Insert(Tours)`

I have attached screenshots of my code.

What i have tried:

- `_=>_.Insert(It.IsAny<Tours>())`

```
[Test]
public void Insert_ToursAreInsertedToTable()
{
   var tour = GetSampleTours()[0];

   var mock = AutoMock.GetLoose();
   mock.Mock<ITourRepository>()
       .Setup(_ => _.Insert(tour));

   var cls = mock.Create<DatabaseLogic>();

   cls.InsertTours(tour);

   mock.Mock<ITourRepository>()
       .Verify(_=>_.Insert(It.IsAny<Tours>()), Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

Subject under test

```
public class DatabaseLogic
{
    public ITourRepository TourRepository = new TourRepository();

    public ObservableCollection<Tours> LoadTours()
    {
        ObservableCollection<Tours> tourCollection = new();

        var getTours = TourRepository.GetTours();

        foreach (var tours in getTours.ToList().Select(variable => new Tours
        {
            TourId = variable.TourId,
            TourName = variable.TourName,
            TourSource = variable.TourSource,
            TourDestination = variable.TourDestination,
            TourDistance = variable.TourDistance,
            TourDescription = variable.TourDescription,
            TourRoute = variable.TourRoute
        }))
        {
            tourCollection.Add(tours);
        }

        return tourCollection;
    }

    public void InsertTours(Tours tours)
    {
        tours.TourRoute = tours.TourSource + "_" + tours.TourDestination;
        TourRepository.Insert(tours);
    }

    public void DeleteTours(Tours tourData)
    {
        TourRepository = new TourRepository();

        var tours = new Tours
        {
            TourName = tourData.TourName
        };

        TourRepository.Delete(tours.TourId);

    }
}
```

Comment: How is the property `TourRepository` initialized?

Comment: @KlausGütter i initialized it in the class DatabaseLogic as: public ITourRepository TourRepository = new TourRepository();

Comment: The repository should be explicitly injected into the subject under test via constructor injection.

Comment: @TheWaII Show `DatabaseLogic` including constructor, dependencies. You have already provided the subject member under test but without know about the other variables there wont be enough context about the subject

Comment: The subject class is tightly coupled to implementation details which make isolating it for unit tests difficult. Refactor the class to depend on the abstraction use explicit dependency principle via constructor injection.

Comment: @Nkosi thank you so much. I looked into constructor injection and my test works now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

I extended the class `DatabaseLogic` with the following:

```
private readonly ITourRepository _iTourRepository = new TourRepository();

DatabaseLogic(ITourRepository iTourRepository)
{
    _tourTourRepository = iTourRepository;
}
```